# What Discard all changes in Xcode source control actually does?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, version-control

As in question, I wonder if there is some documentation about what this Xcode command does (Source Control -> Discard all changes) ?

I guess it reverts to last commit but on local branch ? Can somebody confirm that it doesn't affect the same remote branch automatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't use git in XCode, but I can be so sure that `Discard all changes` will **NOT** affect history in the remote.

It will most probably discard all *unstaged* changes you made to the tracked files in the working directory, simply like executing `git checkout -- .` from the terminal.

With *unstaged*, it means changes you once executed `git add -u` for will not be discarded.

By the way, to find out what it actually does, a test by yourself is needed.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response. Yeah, it seems that most of what you've said is true. Still, I would like to hear / read something official about this, rather than to rely on my own tests. Of course your answer is informative and you have my upvote for the effort, but still I can't accept it, because it seems that you are not 100% positive about discarding unstaged changes and in what you said in whole. So I will left question opened for a while (or maybe I will start a bounty).

Comment: I tested this and it certainly doesnt affect the remote branch. Just forgot to get back with results. Again :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem in which I wanted to roll back to my most recent local commit, and being unfamiliar with command line git, I took a chance with selecting 'Discard Changes in /*filename*/' and it did exactly the same thing all the websites said git checkout would do.

Once again, this is just my "test" but the feature works as advertised.

Comment: Yup. It discards all changes so you get back to the last commit.